# Angular2 directive - string issue

Tags: angular, typescript

We created a **directive** in **Angular2** and have an `input` property that should receive a `string`. The problem is that, we are not able to pass a string.

If we try to do this:

```
<learning-requirements [title]="You should be able to!" [content]="requirements"></learning-requirements>
```

It does not work, so we have to do this, and then it works:

```
<learning-requirements [title]="'You should be able to!'" [content]="requirements"></learning-requirements>
```

That is our directive:

```
@Component({
    selector: "learning-requirements",
    directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: "build/pages/learning/components/requirements/requirements.html"
})
export class RequirementsComponent {
    @Input() public title: string;
    @Input("content") public items: Array<Requirement>;
}
```

Any idea how to handle string whithout explicitly using single quotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically whenever you have attribute wrap with `[]` square bracket it is going to evaluated attribute value(expression) with context(`this`) of component.

**Since you're directly passing a value you could directly specify `title` attribute without `[]` square bracket**, which means that the value which you have passed inside attribute would not get evaluated against context(`this`) of component.

**Markup**

```
<learning-requirements 
  title="You should be able to!" 
  [content]="requirements">
</learning-requirements>
```

Comment: @dag Glad to hear that it helped, Thanks and cheers, you could find same [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39393526/2435473)

Answer (score 2):

Declare string(Type) variable and use it as shown below,

```
<learning-requirements [title]="someVar" [content]="requirements"></learning-requirements>


export class AppComponent{
  someVar:string="You should be able to!";
}
```

Comment: Ok, I know this, but is there a way to tell the directive that it's a string to avoid single quotes?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say. What's your point after this answer?

Comment: If you don't want to use variable, you have to pass it with single quote.